# Custom tile based map is slow

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am working on a map for my public transit app. I'm using SurfaceView, it's a tile based map, there are 2 threads besides the main thread - drawing thread and bitmap loading thread.

Bitmaps are 256x256 PNGs stored on the SD card, I am caching the loaded bitmaps, cache capacity is 64 bitmaps. There are different sets of bitmaps for every zoom level, my map has 4 zoom levels, every next level is 2x more zoomed.

Unfortunately scrolling and pinch zooming is not smooth on my Nexus One, FPS is 15 - 20. When no tiles are being loaded FPS is 35 - 40. If I lower priority of the bitmap loading thread, it becomes completely smooth but I often see not yet loaded (white) tiles on the map - which is even worse than the non-smoothness.

So what could I do? I have 2 ideas so far:

- Try OpenGL, but I don't want to spend time on it and then find out it my FPS only inreased by 3. Also I want to show popups (that scroll with the map) after user clicks on map markers, which I don't know how to do in GLSurfaceView.
- Set low priority to bitmap loading thread only when user touches the screen or when there's an ongoing animation. I tried that but for unknown reason it seemed to even worsen the problem a little bit, touching / not touching the screen didn't have any effect. If it was just some bug I can fix, there's still another problem. If I use kinetic scroll to quickly move the map, I will see many not cached bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do *any* I/O on your rendering thread. (How can you be using GLSurfaceView and not using OpenGL by the way?)

I have written an OpenGL tile-based map view and it is smooth as butter on a Nexus One (not measured the fps but it's *easily* as smooth as the maps app on an iPhone 4). The trick is to move all I/O off the rendering thread, lower the priorities of your worker threads, and to immediately requestRender() at the end of the current render if you know another's going to be needed (such as during a pan or zoom), i.e. don't wait for that to be signalled by another thread. Look for Yell.com in the Market to see it in action (may be UK-only though).

Comment: Sorry, it should be SurfaceView, I edited the question. What makes you think that I am doing IO in rendering thread? I have a drawing thread plus additional bitmap loading (IO) thread.

Comment: What about decoding the .pngs? That needs to be done on your loading thread too. And your loading thread must have a lower priority or it'll still starve your UI thread of CPU time. If you're already doing all of that it could be that you're just seeing how slow the 2D Canvas drawing APIs are.

Comment: What about your approach? Are you drawing each visible tile every frame? That'd be very slow... far better to use an off-screen bitmap to which you draw new tiles only as they become visible.

Comment: If the loading thread has lower priority, new bitmaps are loaded too slowly. So far the best compromise is to have equal priority for bothdrawing and loading threads. I don't think I understand your last comment - if there's an ongoing animation I must draw every visible tile. I'm now trying to implement correctly my second idea (that's described in the question), I hope it will help...

Comment: What does your onDraw(Canvas) function look like? Does it iterate through visible tiles and draw each one seperately? Because that will be slower than keeping an offscreen bitmap which you scroll and only draw new tiles when they become visible. Your onDraw is then a single drawBitmap() call. I know this cos I wrote a 2D sidescroller game (Mole Miner in the Market) which had to solve roughly the same problem. The thing to remember is that one big blit is quicker than a number of smaller blits.

Comment: That's quite interesting - because number of drawn pixels is equal. I will try that (I'm now calling drawBitmap for every visible tile).

Comment: BTW I noticed your another app - Cycle Hire Widget. The app I'm working on is also for London, it's on the Market as "Pubtran London", the map will be in the next version.

Comment: The larger blit gets to exploit a ton more CPU cache efficiency than lots of smaller blits will. Of course you have to do those smaller blits *anyway*, to the offscreen, but way less frequently than every frame. Btw I'd recommend not doing any scaling on the offscreen bitmap... keep that for your final render. And your offscreen should be larger than the screen, i.e. a multiple of your map tile size in both dimensions. Since scrolling is expensive you'll be scrolling your offscreen by whole tiles, not pixels. Make sense?

Comment: Go download the Yell.com app from Market if you want to see my OpenGL-based map in action. It's worth a look IMNSHO, especially the compass mode.

Comment: I understand now, thanks... I don't see the Yell.com on the Market though (I'm not from UK).